# draw image from two dimensional boolean array in android

Tags: android, android-bitmap

i have two dimensional array of integers (0/1), and i want to convert it to image in my android application.
can any one guide me how to do that, i have no idea and couldn't get anything from researches.
i have try to do that in java desktop application as follow

```
image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // Go through the array and set the pixel color on the BufferedImage 
    // according to the values in the array.
    for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++){
            // If the point is in the Set, color it White, else, color it Black.
            if(values[i][j]) image.setRGB(i, j, Color.YELLOW.getRGB());
            if(!values[i][j]) image.setRGB(i, j, Color.PINK.getRGB());
        }
    }
```

but i don't know how to do that in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test but this may help:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Config.ARGB_8888);
for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++){
            if(values[i][j]) image.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(a, r, g, b));
            if(!values[i][j]) image.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(a, r, g, b));
        }
}
```

Comment: many thanks, after testing  just dont use getRGB method.
 the solution is:
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Config.ARGB_8888);
for(int i=0;i<WIDTH;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++){
            if(values[i][j]) image.setPixel(i, j, Color.YELLOW);
            if(!values[i][j]) image.setPixel(i, j, Color.PINK);
        }
}

Comment: yes, after I confirm it I've changed my answer to user Color.argb() method. Color.nameOfColor works too ;)